# Patterns for default Properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, default, higher-order-components

We inject a List of Components into a Card Component. This Card component has a GUI overlay, which allows Users to Choose the Component used and their Properties.

[According to Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650) `FunctionalComponent.defaultProps` will eventually be deprecated, which we used in our first prototype to bubble the required values upstream.

```
const Field = ({text}) => <div>{text}</div>
Field.defaultProps = {text: "Default Value"}
```

Our second Approach was adding a HOC receiving a callback from Card to provide the prop defaults this way.

```
const withGUI = (defaults, Component) => props => {
    const cb = props.onDefaultsChange
    useEffect(() => cb?.(defaults), [cb])
    return <Component {...props}/>
}

const Field = withGUI({text: "Default Value"}, ({text}) => <div>{text}</div>)
```

Our third approch simplified the HOC to

```
const withGUI = (defaults, Component) => {
    Component.gui_props = defaults
    return Component
}
```

Do the Approaches 1 and 3 differ enough to avoid interfering with the potential deprecation?